# Search for a string which is stretched over 2 lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i search for this string `abcdefgh` in a very large file like this and i don't know at which position the new line begin. My first thought was to remove all `\n`, but the file is over 3 gb ... I think there is smart way to do this (sed, awk, ...?)

```
efhashivia
hjasjdjasd
oqkfoflABC
DEFGHqpclq
pasdpapsda
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then, it's highly encouraged for users to add efforts in their question, thank you cheers.

Comment: If you can put a limit on the number of lines the string can span, then you can use sed, awk for a fast solution.

Comment: The maximum of span are two lines.

Comment: ```ggrep  -i "ABCDEFGH" <(paste -d ' ' - - <input.txt | sed 's/ //')```work for me. 2nd run i delete the first row, so i should find all pattern distributed over 2 lines

Comment: What do you want to do when you find this string? Print out the line(s) it's on?

Comment: You shouldn't `paste` file with itself, but itself excluding the first line, so that you merge every line with its next one. Also you can set an empty delimiter, no need to pipe to `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your search string cannot expand into more than 2 lines, you can use this `awk`:

```
awk -v p="ABCDEFGH" 's $0 ~ p {print NR,s $0} {s=$0}' file
```

---

Or you can `paste` each line with its next one, and `grep` the result. This way you have to create a file with double size of your large input.

```
tail -n +2 file | paste -d '' file - > output.txt

> cat output.txt
efhashiviahjasjdjasd
hjasjdjasdoqkfoflABC
oqkfoflABCDEFGHqpclq
DEFGHqpclqpasdpapsda
pasdpapsda

> grep -n ABCDEFGH output.txt
3:oqkfoflABCDEFGHqpclq
```